# Navigation animation backwards

Tags: html, css

Why animation on nav bar, that red line, if you set 100% width on `nav li a::after` works backward and not from left to right side how it should be or how I want to?

HTML

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Domů</a></li>
                <li><a href="switcher.php">Fun Switcher</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Radio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fotky</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chat</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    grid-area: nav;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1em 0;
}

nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 3em;
    position: relative;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav li a::after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 0.4em;
    background-color: red;
    bottom: -1em;
   /* width: 100%; look for whole line */
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav li a:hover::after {
    width: 60%;
}

nav li a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: beacouse the divs are set backwards and the font is set on the right side. I gonna check the code for a solution

Answer (score 1):

You want to change multiple things because some css property is not appropriate for your html class...

```css
nav {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    grid-area: nav;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}

nav li {
    padding: 13px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    position: relative;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav li a::after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 0.4em;
    background-color: red;
    bottom: -1em;
   /* width: 100%; look for whole line */
    transition: all ease-in-out 350ms;
    left: 0;
    width:0;
}

nav li a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}

nav li a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Domů</a></li>
            <li><a href="switcher.php">Fun Switcher</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Radio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fotky</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Chat</a></li>
         </ul>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this an accpetable solution for you?

```css
`a{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  }`
```

add this to your css code

heres my codepen:
https://codepen.io/oskedram/pen/abWREpg

Comment: @Kernel Panic tell me when something isnt right

Comment: Well that center the line, which is cool. But I would like to use that animation from left side to right side, when you put cursor on any of the nav element.. It still change animation from right side to left side.... I dont know what is wrong

Comment: @Kernel Panic so you want to animate it to start from left ang go to right like a loading bar or do you want the red line to be placed more on the left?

Comment: `nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 3em;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}`

That set the line to the left side, so it is fine.. But then when I want to make animation from left side to right side with that `transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;` it works from right side to left side. And I want to make that animation from left side to right side

Comment: If that help you, I want to make that line work like that, just the line will be visible only when you move cursor on that menu text `<div></div><style>
  div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

div:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>`

Comment: @Kernel Panic now it makes more sente to me, thank you. Will look ofr a solution

Comment: @Kernel Panic well somebody put the answer before me(Faeemazaz Bhanej). But i hope i could help a little ;)